# How to set Java environmental variables through python in a AWS Glue job

Tags: python, aws-glue

I am trying to set the JAVA environmental variables through python code in an AWS Glue job. I have tried multiple ways but no luck.

[image]

After trying several different ways I found this helpful but this event didn't work for me. What can I try next?

Comment: post the code and not the pictures of code.
Users need to be able to replicate the problem quickly, 
which text allows for (and pictures do not).
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: The image looks like a photograph of a Stack Overflow answer. If you want to refer to an answer here, use the "Share" link, rather than a photo. Thanks!